# Apple iPad app update frequency

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-appstore, software-update

I'm the Intune MDM administrator for my company, and I'm trying to ensure the required apps on our devices are updated in a timely fashion.  I've had a look around to see if I can find any details around conditions or timings for iPad (and to a lesser extent, iPhone) app updates so I can set expectations appropriately, but only managed to find one anecdotal post that was never answered when asked for references.

Does anyone know if this sort of info is available, and if so, where I might find it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you talking about apps available on the App Store or enterprise apps managed by the organization?

Comment: App Store apps. In this case, it's an app internally developed, and distributed both internally and to external paying customers through the App Store, and it still goes through the standard Apple approval process for apps. So when they get an update approved, I'm trying to work out when our devices will get them.

Comment: As soon as an app or update thereof is approved from Apple, it becomes available for publishing on the App Store (you can configure it to auto publish). It's totally in your control to manage the update frequency (based on business needs of your organization and users). The iOS devices could be configured to automatically download and install app updates.

Comment: Yep, totally get all that.  Our devs release the app, get it reviewed by Apple, and then manually release it once approved.  I have the devices configured to automatically update.  However, I have two devices sitting next to me that have been on all day (9 hours) and have yet to auto update.  So I'm wondering things like, do they update when the screen is off, do they need power to update, how often do they check in with Apple to see if updates are available, do Apple stagger updates to devices (I've read anecdotally people saying updates took 1 day to some devices, and 3 days to others), etc

Comment: Writing this from personal experience with no source to back: In theory automatic updates should work soon after an update is released for an installed app on the App Store. On an iOS device, is the screen is turned off, the Wi-Fi generally disconnects after around 30 mins of inactivity. I believe there's some mechanism in the iOS subsystem that momentarily turns on the connection after some duration to check for things like background app refresh and other background activity.

Comment: Also, there may be a criterion of having some amount of battery charge on device to install app updates. If you manage the app releases yourself, you can be in the loop when an update gets approved. I'm not sure if Apple does or does not stagger updates. You can utilize your MDM subsystem to push app installs/updates which I understand will certainly install it on devices.

Comment: I thought MDM merely set the update policy (config), and that the actual updates were still controlled by App Store? And yeah, I've read a few theories that people had around Wifi disconnection and % charge needed; of the two test systems I mentioned, one is plugged in and the other isn't, to see if I can observe any difference. And my end devices are in clinics where we get them to leave them on overnight, but some still seem to be having trouble, and I'd like to understand the conditions needed

Comment: The conditions aren’t publicly documented by Apple. So any learning has to happen by hit and trial. And on top of that, things are liable to change with every iOS update. So that’s that.